# Module not found even package path has the file

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I've installed `vue-tel-input` package while importing `css` it causes the error mentioned below, even I've checked the file is there in the `node_modules` folder.

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 32:0-46

Module not found: Error: Package path ./dist/vue-tel-input.css is not exported from package 

H:\xampp\htdocs\app\node_modules\vue-tel-input (see exports field in 
H:\xampp\htdocs\app\node_modules\vue-tel-input\package.json)

Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?
```

Do anyone guide me about it?